# Historical data for non-expired option contracts with ib_insync lib?

Tags: python, tws

I would like to get historical data (ideally hourly or less) for non-expired option contracts. TWS API should provide that data (source: https://www.tradersinsight.news/ibkr-quant-news/historical-options-futures-data-using-tws-api/). I have not found a way to get that data using the beautiful ib_insync lib. Is there a way to do that? If so, how?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This works in the same way you fetch historical data for a stock, you just need to define an Option contract as "contract" `reqHistoricalData()`.

For example, first, you define e.g. a monthly NVIDIA call expiring on Friday 15th March 2024:

```
from ib_insync import IB, util, Option
ib = IB()

...

contract = Option(
    symbol="NVDA",
    lastTradeDateOrContractMonth="20240315",
    strike=800,
    right="C",
    exchange="SMART",
    tradingClass="NVDA"
    )
```

Then you get the historical data, in this case 5 minute bars of the last 5 days.

```
bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
    contract=contract,
    endDateTime = "",
    durationStr = "5 D",
    barSizeSetting = "5 Mins",
    whatToShow = "TRADES",
    useRTH = True,
    formatDate = 1,
    keepUpToDate = False
    )
```

Afterwards you proceed with `df = util.df(bars)` to store the data in a dataframe.